# Laravel - Rate limit of once per 5 seconds

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make it so that a user can only post every 5 seconds, as some of my users accidentally post the same thing when double clicking sometimes.

The thing is, this code seems to make it so that I can post 5 times maximum per second. But that's not what I want.

```
RateLimiter::for('submission', function (Request $request) {
    return Limit::perSeconds(5)->response(function () {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Please wait before posting another submission.');
    });
});
```

How do I make it so that the limiter only "releases" after 5 seconds of posting?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the rate limiter directly in your controller ? It allows a decay rate in seconds, the route rate limiter is only in minutes...

The doc says :

> If necessary, you may provide a fourth argument to the attempt method,
> which is the "decay rate", or the number of seconds until the
> available attempts are reset. For example, we can modify the example
> above to allow five attempts every two minutes:

This should be once every 5 seconds :

```
$executed = RateLimiter::attempt(
    'send-message:'.$user->id,
    1, // Number of attempts
    function() {
        // Do your action...
    },
    $decayRate = 5,
);
if(!$executed) {
    // redirect
}
```